# Angular 2 component inside other component

Tags: angular, angular2-components

Creating an RPG character creator.

I have a NewCharacterComponent and I am trying to implement a DieInputComponent inside it. The NewCharacterComponent is routed from an AppComponent. Important snippets of the code will be below.

The issue I am running into is that I am not getting the DieInputComponent to load within the NewCharacterComponent. When I break the DieInputComponent code no errors are thrown in the console, so the error is likely that I am just not successfully importing the DieInputComponent but I just have no idea what is going wrong.

new-character.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import { DieInputComponent } from './die-input.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'core-worlds',
  templateUrl: 'app/new-character.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/new-character.component.css'],
})

export class NewCharacterComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

new-character.component.html

```
<h2>New Character</h2>
<die-input></die-input>
```

die-input.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'die-input',
    templateUrl: 'app/die-input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/die-input.component.css'],
})

export class DieInputComponent {
    constructor() { }
}
```

die-input.component.html

```
<input type="number" placeholder="1d4"></input>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have your `die-input` component recognized, you'll need to inform Angular about its existence, through the `directives` option in the configuration object passed to the @Component decorator:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import { DieInputComponent } from './die-input.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'core-worlds',
  templateUrl: 'app/new-character.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/new-character.component.css'],
  directives: [ DieInputComponent ] //<<<< Where the magic happens
})

export class NewCharacterComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked. I had done the Tour of Heroes tutorial but I don't think I had gotten a true grasp on what the directives actually did.

Comment: Sadly it is now depreacated, we have to use now a declaration in our module

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use the component often & within multiple components, you can also provide it within your `main.ts`.

`provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: <ComponentName>, multi: true})`

This will essentially add it to primary directives collection so that it is accessed just like the built-in directives.

**main.ts**

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, provide } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DieInputComponent} from './die-input.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: DieInputComponent, multi: true}),
]);
```

**new-character.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

@Component({
  selector: 'core-worlds',
  templateUrl: 'app/new-character.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/new-character.component.css'],
})

export class NewCharacterComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

**new-character.component.html**

```
<h2>New Character</h2>
<die-input></die-input>
```