# Angular module/component - display on own as well as inside another module/component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Let's say I have `ModuleA` with a router entry of:

```
path: 'modulea',
loadChildren: './modulea/modulea.module#ModuleA'
```

`ComponentA` (`ComponentA`'s selector is `component-a`)

`ModuleB` with a router entry of:

```
path: 'moduleb',
loadChildren: './moduleb/moduleb.module#ModuleB'
```

`ComponentB` (`ComponentB`'s selector is `component-b`)

`ComponentA`'s template has `<div class="component-a">...</div>` and if I go to mysite.com/modulea I see everything I expect to see.

However, I cannot get it to display in `ComponentB`'s template like so:

```
<div class="component-b">
   Do some stuff

   <div class="component-a"></div>

   Do more stuff
</div>
```

Which kind of makes sense to me because at that point I feel like I am basically overriding `ComponentA`'s template (even if it's failing for some other reason).

Nor can I get it to display `ComponentA` inside `ComponentB` by switching `<div class="component-a"></div>` with `<component-a></component-a>` to it.

The closest I have found to what I am trying to do is, [Angular 2 component inside other component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903412/angular-2-component-inside-other-component). This looks promising, but when I try to add `ComponentA` as a directive to `ComponentB` and use `<component-a></component-a>`, it throws an error that " 'component-a' is not a known element..."

TL;DR:

I want my module/component to display on its own page in my application, as well as be displayed inside another module/component elsewhere in the application.

Comment: not sure i understand you 100% but on first reading seems like you need `content projection`. good video on the topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTwKhxLZ3jI

Comment: Thank you, I'll look at that and see if it helps.  Basically I just want my component A to have its own page/route in the application, as well as be used inside another component/module.

Comment: yes, that should be it. `ng-content` is your keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be exporting `componentA` from your `moduleA`, so that you can safely use it in `componentB`, by importing `ModuleA` in `ModuleB`.

This will resolve your error

> " 'component-a' is not a known element..."

moduleA.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
declarations:[ComponentA],
exports:[ComponentA]
})
export class ModuleA{
}
```

moduleB.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
declarations:[ComponentB],
imports:[ModuleA]
})
export class ModuleB{
}
```

componentB.component.ts

```
<div class="component-b">
   Do some stuff

   <component-a></component-a>

   Do more stuff
</div>
```

Comment: I think what I was missing was the `exports: [ComponentA]` in `ModuleA`!  Thank you!  Now I just have to figure out how to read data from `ComponentA` in `ComponentB`, but that's a whole different question, haha.